# How can I use ResultReceiver in InputMethodManager#hideSoftInputFromWindow

Tags: android, ime

I have some code:

```
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0, new ResultReceiver(null) {
     @Override
     protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
          keyboardClosed();
     }
});
```

However, running this on a 4.3 emulator the `onReceiveResult()` method is never called.
I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but can't see what...

Can anyone provide me with either some details of how to do this properly or why it isn't working?

Comment: Does your emulator pop up the IME keyboard?

Comment: It *hides* the IME keyboard (which is what this code is supposed to do). Previously the code read:

inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
keyboardClosed();

In that case, everything worked fine.

Comment: And does the callback work on a real device? If so, you just got yet another emulator bug. If not, IDK and can't help you more as you code should indeed work. Good luck.

Comment: The callback also fails to work on a real device (Galaxy S2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ResultReceiver` is not called if `hideSoftInputFromWindow` returns `false`.
 You can check this value:

```
boolean hide = inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0, new ResultReceiver(null) {
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
       keyboardClosed();
    }
});
if (!hide) {
    // already hidden
    keyboardClosed();
}
```

Comment: You are my savior. So easy to miss.

Comment: but... uh... why did it return 'false'?

Comment: For real. The docs do not say anything about the return value